# Merge two pdf files without re-rendering?

Tags: pdf, merge, pdf-generation

We have to combine multiple (typically up to 100) single pdf pages into a single pdf document. Currently, we are using FreePDF for the merge, which has two disadvantages: we always seem to loose a little detail and it takes about a minute to merge 500 files (and we have to merge millions in a limited timeframe).

Is it at all possible to combine pdfs lossless and without a rendering process? I was thinking about a byte array method (we are happy to program something or use a lib).

Other than that, can someone recommend a lib / program that will perform better than FreePDF for the merge operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using **[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)**. Take a look at this sample: **http://gnaresh.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/c-code-to-merge-multiple-pdfs-into-single-pdf/**

Or you can use **[Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com)** library for that (which would be most reliable).

If you need **Ghostscript wrapper for .NET** take a look at here: **[Ghostscript.NET](http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com)**

If you want to do that via Ghostscript User interface (without programming knowledge), you can download **[Ghostscript Studio (IDE)](http://ghostscriptstudio.codeplex.com)** and use this switches in the Ghostscript Processor to merge multiple PDF's into a single PDF:

```
! >> interaction-related parameters
-dBATCH         ! keep gs out from going into interactive loop reading
-dNOPAUSE       ! disables the prompt and pause at the end of each page

! >> device selection parameters
-sDEVICE = pdfwrite     ! pdf device
```

Comment: Thank you, HABJAN. Do you know if iTextSharp will re-render the files? My guess is that it will. I am not sure if it is possible to glue pdfs together without re-rendering. We need this to be really fast, like at least 25 (one page) documents combined into one pdf in one second on a single 3 GHz core. Do you have a guess or experience about the possible speed with iTextSharp or GhostScript? With PDFFree we were able to merge about 8 documents per second.

Comment: You are welcome. iTextSharp will not 're-render' your PDFs. It will copy pdf objects and content bytes without rasterizing them. I'm not sure about the speed, but it should be fast enough i think. Everything depends on your code/logic implementation. Speed can vary based on your PDF content and structure. Check out this article: http://cjhaas.com/blog/2011/10/13/speed-up-itextsharps-pdfreader-when-reading-multiple-files-or-one-very-large-file/

Comment: Thank you once again HABJAN, your information is very helpful to us.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [cpdf command line tools](http://community.coherentpdf.com/):

```
cpdf file1.pdf file2.pdf ....... file100.pdf -o out.pdf
```

No rerendering occurs, and it should be fast and have no problem with large numbers of files.

Free for non-commercial use.

Comment: Thank you, the lincense could be a hindernis, though. We will try this should iTExtSharp fail on us.